# How to use the feedback function in Matlab when we have nothing in the feedback loop?

Tags: control, matlab

Matlab's feedback function is used to obtain the closed loop transfer function of a system. Example:

[image]

`sys = feedback(sys1,sys2)` returns a model object sys for the negative feedback interconnection of model objects `sys1`,`sys2`.  To compute the closed-loop system with positive feedback, use sign = +1, for negative feedback we use -1.

My question arises when we have a system of the following type:

[image]

According to these [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/feedback.html#d117e51709), we can use feedback to create the negative feedback loop with G and C.

```
sys = feedback(G*C,-1)
```

This is a source of confusion, shouldn't the above be:  `sys = feedback(G*C,1,-1)?` These are not the same.

However, looking at these [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ug/assessing-gain-and-phase-margins.html), for a unit loop gain k, you can compute the closed-loop transfer function T using:

```
G = tf([.5 1.3],[1 1.2  1.6 0]);
T = feedback(G,1);
```

[image]

Why are we using  `1` and not `-1`? This is still negative feedback and not positive feedback.

Comment: feedback(g, 1) gives unitary negative feedback loop. \$feedback(g, 1)=\frac{g}{1+g}\$. That’s the syntax.

Comment: So, it seems like there is a mistake in the documentation